# How do I generate a 160 bit prime number in java?

Tags: java, primes

I want to generate a 160-bit prime number in java. I know that I'll have to loop through all the 160-bit numbers and for any number `n`, I'll have to check if they are divisible by any primes less than `sqroot(n)` or by any primality test like `Miller-Rabin test`. My questions are:

1. Is there any specific library which does this?
2. Is there any other (better) way to do this?

Comment: `"I know that I'll have to loop through all the 160-bit numbers and for any number n"` -- how much time do you have?

Comment: Does "160 bit prime" include primes like 2 or 5?

Comment: @Makoto I think the point being made is that 2 is a 160-bit prime number if you prefix enough zeroes.

Comment: Well, I know doing this might take a lot of time but I don't really know any means to do this. I want to do it fast.

Comment: @DestinyCalling If *one billion* numbers could be looped a second, how many seconds would it take to loop through 2^160 numbers? Hint: 2^x/2^y = 2^(x-y) and there are less than 2^18 seconds per day..

Comment: @Wormbo - No, it doesn't

Comment: @pst - Can _one billion_ numbers be looped in a second?

Comment: @DestinyCalling I picked a large number. Choose 100 billion. Do the same math. Of course, these numbers are high to prove a point. The numbers can't be reached on a consumer system if actual work is done. Looping through that large a space is .. very time consuming.

Comment: @pst- The hint gives me a better idea. Thanks. :-)
But then, honestly, I really don't know how do I select a 160 bit prime.

Comment: Glad you solved it. I figured that with my computer, doing the looping that you described would take over 1 followed by 22 zero (7.440979924644339E22 was my latest calculation) ***years***. Myself, I don't have that much time.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Lolz. Me neither. But I wasn't much knowledgeable about this until I posted my question here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`BigInteger.probablePrime(160, new Random())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#probablePrime%28int,%20java.util.Random%29) generates a `BigInteger` that is almost certainly prime -- the probability that it is *not* a prime is less than the probability that you will get struck by lightning.  In general, `BigInteger` already has heavily tested and optimized primality testing operations built in.

For what it's worth, the reason this won't take forever is that by the prime number theorem, a randomly chosen n-bit number has probability proportional to 1/n of being prime, so on average you only need to try O(n) different random n-bit numbers before you'll find one that's prime.

Comment: Well... that beats my "generate a 320-bit RSA key and steal the prime" idea :-(

Comment: I wonder if the primes in Java-generated RSA keys are any more likely to be prime. I guess they probably use this method under the covers.

Comment: Athough, is `new Random()` a recommend PRNG in this case? It seems like, if wanting to find probable primes (for cryto?) a better source would be desired.

Comment: Depends entirely on what you want it for.

Comment: @DuncanJones Java is open source for most parts. Don't guess, look up the code :)

Comment: Just a side note: sometimes you doesn't need a prime but a relative prime, in such a case you can run an euclidean GCD algorithm and check whether its result is 1 (if not, call `.nextProbablePrime()` and repeat).