# How do I get a N digit random "industrial grade" prime number where 5 < N < 20?

Tags: java, random, primes

What am doing wrong here in this piece of code ? What is a better way to generate N digit random number ?

```
public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
if (n <= 3) {
    return n > 1;
} else if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    for (int i = 5; i * i <= n; i += 6) {
        if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

```
public static long getPrime(int digit){
    long sample;
    long multiple = Math.round(Math.pow(10, digit));
    do{         
        sample = Math.round(Math.random()* multiple);
        //System.out.println(sample);
    }while(!isPrime(sample));
    return sample;
}
```

Comment: Your  test `isPrime` will get you [Fermat pseudoprimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime) to bases 2 and 3, which are not necessarily primes. Are you okay with that?

Comment: Also, why not use an [already available method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15056355/3717023)?

Comment: Yes..I could add more to it to eliminate Charmichaels numbers.

Comment: Ok I got a better isPrime method from wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test. It just takes a while after N = 10. I need a better sampling !

Comment: I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getPrime()` method is nearly right for `5 < N < 19`. It won't work for `N = 19` because the largest possible `long` value is `9223372036854775807` which is 19 digits long. The reason it doesn't quite work for values lower than 19 is that it can produce numbers with fewer than the required number of digits. You need `while(sample < (long) Math.pow(10, digit - 1) || !isPrime(sample))`

Now that you have updated your `isPrime()` method, it almost works, but you need to replace

```
for (int i = 5; i * i <= n; i += 6)
```

by

```
for (long i = 5; i * i <= n; i += 6)
```

because otherwise the value of `i * i` can overflow.

Comment: Thank you sir ! This does it. I don't know why other ppl marked this question as negative but it helped me. Have a good one :)

Comment: user2036385 I've just realised it still doesn't do it. `getPrime(16)` works but `getPrime(17)` doesn't. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: One thing we could do is : for (long i = 5; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 6) , though it still doesn't go beyond 16

Comment: Try this: sample = Math.round(Math.random()* multiple) + Math.round(rnd * 100); The Math.random() function returns a double with 17 decimals only so we will have to give it two digits more.

Comment: You've cracked it. And I know why. When N = 17 or 18, the value of `Math.round(Math.random()* multiple)` is always even. The easiest way to fix it is to do `Math.round(Math.random() * multiple) - 1`. You don't want to add stuff on because it might then have too many digits. That was REALLY complicated. I agree with you that it was a really good question. People on this site often downvote questions before they've even thought about them. I've upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

> What am doing wrong here in this piece of code:

Lots of things.

1. Your test for primality is mathematically bogus as noted by the commenters.
2. You have implemented the test incorrectly.  The `Math.pow(...)` function returns an `double`, so you are liable suffer from loss of precision.  But you need full precision for the remainder operation (`%`) to give you the correct answer.
3. You are ignoring the perfectly serviceable prime number generation and primality test methods that are provided by the standard `BigInteger` class; see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for details.

My guess is that point #2 is what you are missing.

Comment: Thanks for your input Stephen. I am just trying to learn arithmetic operations in JVM. Could you please suggest some improvements that will bring me closer to the soln.

Comment: You cannot implement this using `long` and/or `Math.pow()`.  The best solution is to just use BigInteger and its existing prime / primality methods.

Comment: Indeed, `long` has a range that is shorter than 20 decimal digits (about 19) and the `double` type you are forced to use when calling `Math.pow()` has even less digits precision. Yes, `double` can express values with 20 and more digits before the decimal point, but all but the first about 15 to 16 will be either zero or some other result of rounding to the nearest representable value. Just use `BigInteger`, this kind of calculation is not possible with simple types.

Answer (score 1):

Math.random() has only 15-16 digits of precision so won't produce all 16, 17, 18, 19 or 20 digit numbers.  The problem is that the 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 digits are far more likely to be multiples of 2, 4, 8, 16 and 32 respectably and thus not prime.

I suggest you use SecureRandom.nextLong() taking the lower N digits.

Comment: This could be a good idea but how do you efficiently take the lower N digits ?

Comment: @user2036385 You could use `% N` and add `N - 1` if negative.